# Por que la variable Ciudad1 no guarda el valor en la primera ejecucion del modal, y por el contrario en segunda ejecucion si lo hace

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc

```js
document.getElementById("BtnModal").onclick = Public;

Ciudad1 = "";

function Publication(){
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
 function showPosition(position){
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  latlonmarker= new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlonmarker },geocoderact);
  }
  return Ciudad1;
 }

 function geocoderact(results, status){
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[0]) {
  Ciudad= results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
  Ciudad1 = Ciudad;

  } else {
  error('Google no retorno resultado alguno.');
  }
  } else {
  error("Geocoding fallo debido a : " + status);
  }

}

function Public(){
 var Resul=Publication();
 alert(Resul);
 $.ajax({
        url: "Public.html",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
   success : function(data) {
    console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
    display(data);
   },
   error : function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    display(e);
   },
   done : function(e) {
    console.log("DONE");
   }
  });
}

function display(data) {
 var info = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
   + data + "</pre>";
 $('#Barrio').html(info);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examinemos tu código:

```
function Publication(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    function showPosition(position){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        lat=position.coords.latitude;
        lon=position.coords.longitude;
        latlonmarker= new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlonmarker },geocoderact);
        }
        return Ciudad1;
 }
```

Se observa que la llamada a tu función `geocoderact` es un **callback**; es decir, es asíncrona y no se ejecuta en el orden en el que crees; tu función Publication retorna Ciudad1 **antes** de que tu función `geocoderact` la modifique.

El comportamiento exacto de tu código es:

1. ... varias acciones ...
2. colocamos la llamada a `geocoderact` en la cola de eventos pendientes.
3. ... otras acciones ...
4. devolvemos Ciudad1, que aún no ha sido modificada.

`Resto de código a ejecutar hasta que lleguemos al return final ...`

Cuando llegas al último `return` y terminas completamente la ejecución de código secuencial, entones ...

1. El navegador procesa los eventos pendientes.
2. Uno de esos eventos es tu llamada a `geocoderact()`
3. `geocoderact()` cambia el valor de tu variable Ciudad1.
4. El nuevo valor ya está disponible.
5. El navegador sigue procesando otros eventos pendientes.
6. **uno** de esos otros eventos pendientes es tu nueva pulsación al botón, en donde accedes a `Ciudad1` que, ahora si, ya fué modificada.

De hecho, si te fijas en los resultados que te ofrece tu página, cada vez que pulses el botón te mostrar el resultado de **la pulsación anterior**.

En la Mozilla Developer Network lo explican con todo detalle:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

EDITO

Los *callbacks* **SON INEVITABLES** en `Javascript`, debido a su propia naturaleza orientada a eventos; cualquier código que trabaje con la red o con eventos de usuario los usa; la expresión *callbacks hell* (infierno de los *callbacks*) hace referencia a la dificultad de la programación en esta forma, que hace complicado saber en que punto exacto estamos, como llegamos hasta aquí, y adonde iremos después.

En este caso concreto, los cambios **no** son eliminar los *callbacks*, cosa imposible ya que los usa el objeto `geocoder` y no sabemos nada de él.
La solución pasa por *convertir* nuestras funciones en funciones callbacks, es decir, cambiar nuestro modo de programar de *lineal* a *orientado a eventos*:

Para ello, contamos con la función `setTimeout( FUNCTION, TIME )`. Simplemente con que usemos `setTimeout( FunciónALlamar, 0 )` se crea un nuevo evento que se coloca al final de la cola, y el navegador lo procesará cuando pueda.

El código anterior se podría modificar de la siguiente manera:

```
function Publication(){
  . . .
  latlonmarker= new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlonmarker },geocoderact);
 }
}
```

Eliminamos el `return`, que es inútil.

```
function geocoderact(results, status){
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[0]) {
   Ciudad= results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
   Ciudad1 = Ciudad;
   setTimeout( ShowResult, 0 ); // Llamamos a nuestro propio callback.
  } else {
   error('Google no retorno resultado alguno.');
  }
 } else {
  error("Geocoding fallo debido a : " + status);
 }
}
```

Si todo fue bien, llamamos a nuestro propio *callback*, que nos muestre el resultado.

```
function ShowResult( ) {
 alert( Ciudad1 );
}
```

Mostramos el resultado, o hacemos cualquier otra cosa.

```
function Public( ) {
 setTimeout( Publication, 0 ); // Que se ejecute cuando el navegador pueda.
 $.ajax( {
  url: "Public.html",
  . . .
```

Ya no nos hacen falta las variables.

Comment: Gracias! @Trauma como podria hacer para que la funcion geocoderact() no sea callback y ejecuta normal!